# If statement in for loop, index out of range with one additional condition?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, enumerate

I'm trying to create an if statement in a for loop to look at an element in a list and compare it to the next element with enumerate().

```
arr = ["NORTH", "SOUTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST", "NORTH", "WEST"]
liste = []
for idx,i in enumerate(arr):
    if (i == 'NORTH' and arr[idx+1] == 'SOUTH') or (i == 'SOUTH' and arr[idx+1] == 'NORTH') or (i == 'EAST' and arr[idx+1] == 'WEST') or (i == 'WEST' and arr[idx+1] == 'EAST'):
        liste.append(idx)
        liste.append(idx+1)
print(liste)
```

expected

```
[0, 1, 3, 4]
```

got

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [44], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 liste = []
      2 for idx,i in enumerate(arr):
----> 3     if (i == 'NORTH' and arr[idx+1] == 'SOUTH') or (i == 'SOUTH' and arr[idx+1] == 'NORTH') or (i == 'EAST' and arr[idx+1] == 'WEST') or (i == 'WEST' and arr[idx+1] == 'EAST'):
      4         liste.append(idx)
      5         liste.append(idx+1)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

but if the original if is (without the last "or")

```
for idx,i in enumerate(arr):
    if (i == 'NORTH' and arr[idx+1] == 'SOUTH') or (i == 'SOUTH' and arr[idx+1] == 'NORTH') or (i == 'EAST' and arr[idx+1] == 'WEST'):
```

it goes through fine and gives the expected outcome (this case has no reversed west/east anyway, but I of course want it to work for random lists).

What's up with that? It's a codewars problem and I can come up with a workaround myself, so I don't want the solution to the whole problem, I'm just trying to understand why it's behaving this way.
EDIT:
I just realized it's because the last element in the list is actually "WEST" so then it's checking idx+1 which for the last element is not in the list. In that case I would be interested in how to avoid that!

Answer (score 1):

When you reach your last element, idx+1 is out of bounds for the array. You would want to keep that in mind in your logic. One way to resolve is to enumerate over the length-1 of the array so it is never trying to access an index out of bounds.

For example:

```py
arr = ["NORTH", "SOUTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST", "NORTH", "WEST"]
liste = []
for idx,i in enumerate(arr[:len(arr)-1]):
    if (i == 'NORTH' and arr[idx+1] == 'SOUTH') or (i == 'SOUTH' and arr[idx+1] == 'NORTH') or (i == 'EAST' and arr[idx+1] == 'WEST') or (i == 'WEST' and arr[idx+1] == 'EAST'):
        liste.append(idx)
        liste.append(idx+1)
print(liste)
```

outputs `[0,1,3,4]`

Answer (score 0):

When your loop arrives at the last element, it checks for 'WEST' and then tries to check the next element, but there is none. This gives the index error.
A quick fix may be to append an element like 'END', for which none of the checks succeeds. Thus, no element past the end gets checked.

Comment: Perfectly easy idea, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're describing is due to [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). This condition:

```py
i == 'WEST' and arr[idx+1] == 'EAST'
```

will check if `i` is equal to `"WEST"`. **Only when this check passes** will it compare if `arr[idx + 1]` is equal to `"EAST"` -- at which point an `IndexError` occurs. The other three conditions in your `if` statement behave analogously, which is why they don't cause an `IndexError` to occur.

You should create a slice so that you don't check past the last element:

```py
from itertools import islice
for idx, i in enumerate(islice(arr, len(arr) - 1)):
    ...
```